# Populate a table with photos from images folder

Tags: c#

I'm using razor code to retrieve the photo url saved as a string in the database. I'm using this code to get the string:

```
<th>
   <img src="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PicUrl)" width="80">
</th>
```

The result is it's showing the url in the page and the inspector does not show "

Any ideas?

I've tried using "" and a couple of variations I saw on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

[`DisplayNameFor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displaynamefor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) helper used to get display name of the viewmodel property associated with it, i.e. display name set with `DisplayAttribute` (for example, `[Display(Name = "Picture URL")]` will show `Picture URL` in view).

If you want to provide property value into `src` attribute with absolute path, you could try to use the property directly (e.g. `@Model.PicUrl`):

```
<img src="@Model.PicUrl" width="80" ... />
```

Or use `@Url.Content()` if your property contains relative path (e.g. `~/path/to/filename.ext`):

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.PicUrl)" width="80" ... />
```

**Note:**

Make sure that image path contained inside viewmodel property is a valid path, either using relative or absolute path.